# I need to get distinct, sorted products in a list, only showing the products with the lowest price

Tags: xquery

I'm struggling with a XQuery problem. I have an XML product list that contains products from 2 different product catalog systems (due to mergers and acquisitions). Some of the products are duplicated (1 in each system). The duplicates have the same product name, but different prices.

I want to return a list of distinct products that show the cheapest product price. For example, consider this input XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:ProductList xmlns:ns1="http://www.mycorp.com/bus/prod/" xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <ns1:Product>
    <ns1:Id>2</ns1:Id>
    <ns1:Name>Ace Ski Boot</ns1:Name>
    <ns1:Description>An intermediate ski boot</ns1:Description>
    <ns1:Price>109.99</ns1:Price>
    <ns1:Warehouse>CZE_PRAGUE</ns1:Warehouse>
    <ns1:Icon_url/>
    <ns1:Latitude>50.07554</ns1:Latitude>
    <ns1:Longitude>14.4378</ns1:Longitude>
  </ns1:Product>
  <ns1:Product>
    <ns1:Id>SUM10012</ns1:Id>
    <ns1:Name>Ace Ski Boot</ns1:Name>
    <ns1:Description>Intermediate ski boot</ns1:Description>
    <ns1:Price>200.0</ns1:Price>
    <ns1:Warehouse>Seattle</ns1:Warehouse>
    <ns1:Icon_url/>
    <ns1:Latitude>47.60621</ns1:Latitude>
    <ns1:Longitude>-122.33207</ns1:Longitude>
  </ns1:Product>
  <ns1:Product>
    <ns1:Id>4</ns1:Id>
    <ns1:Name>Ace Ski Pole</ns1:Name>
    <ns1:Description>A ski pole for skiers with an intermediate skill level</ns1:Description>
    <ns1:Price>29.99</ns1:Price>
    <ns1:Warehouse>FRA_PARIS</ns1:Warehouse>
    <ns1:Icon_url/>
    <ns1:Latitude>48.856613</ns1:Latitude>
    <ns1:Longitude>2.352222</ns1:Longitude>
  </ns1:Product>
  <ns1:Product>
    <ns1:Id>SUM10022</ns1:Id>
    <ns1:Name>Ace Ski Pole</ns1:Name>
    <ns1:Description>Intermediate ski pole</ns1:Description>
    <ns1:Price>21.950000762939453</ns1:Price>
    <ns1:Warehouse>Seattle</ns1:Warehouse>
    <ns1:Icon_url/>
    <ns1:Latitude>47.60621</ns1:Latitude>
    <ns1:Longitude>-122.33207</ns1:Longitude>
  </ns1:Product>
```

It shows 2 duplicated products. I'm looking to return the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:ProductList xmlns:ns1="http://www.mycorp.com/bus/prod/" xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <ns1:Product>
    <ns1:Id>2</ns1:Id>
    <ns1:Name>Ace Ski Boot</ns1:Name>
    <ns1:Description>An intermediate ski boot</ns1:Description>
    <ns1:Price>109.99</ns1:Price>
    <ns1:Warehouse>CZE_PRAGUE</ns1:Warehouse>
    <ns1:Icon_url/>
    <ns1:Latitude>50.07554</ns1:Latitude>
    <ns1:Longitude>14.4378</ns1:Longitude>
  </ns1:Product>
  <ns1:Product>
    <ns1:Id>SUM10022</ns1:Id>
    <ns1:Name>Ace Ski Pole</ns1:Name>
    <ns1:Description>Intermediate ski pole</ns1:Description>
    <ns1:Price>21.950000762939453</ns1:Price>
    <ns1:Warehouse>Seattle</ns1:Warehouse>
    <ns1:Icon_url/>
    <ns1:Latitude>47.60621</ns1:Latitude>
    <ns1:Longitude>-122.33207</ns1:Longitude>
  </ns1:Product>
```

I have seen XQuery for returning distinct values, but not where you need to select the lowest value of a child (ns1:Price) element. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have XQuery 3.0 available to you, then you can make use of a `group by` expression. For example:

```
xquery version "3.0";

declare namespace ns1 = "http://www.mycorp.com/bus/prod/";

for $product in //ns1:Product
let $product-name := $product/ns1:Name
group by $product-name
return
    <ns1:Product>
    {
        $product[xs:decimal(ns1:Price) eq min($product/xs:decimal(ns1:Price))]
    }
    </ns1:Product>
```

If you don't have XQuery 3.0, but have XQuery 1.0, then you need to first identify the unique product names that you wish to group on by using `fn:distinct-values`, from there you can loop over the unique names and create groups (products which have the same name), which you can then filter with a predicate to determine the cheapest product. For example:

```
xquery version "1.0";

declare namespace ns1 = "http://www.mycorp.com/bus/prod/";

let $unique-product-names := distinct-values(//ns1:Product/ns1:Name)
return
    for $product-name in $unique-product-names
    let $grouped-products := //ns1:Product[ns1:Name eq $product-name]
    let $group-cheapest-price := min($grouped-products/xs:decimal(ns1:Price))
    return
        $grouped-products[xs:decimal(ns1:Price) eq $group-cheapest-price]
```

Comment: Sadly, I only have access to XQuery 1.0 at the moment.

Comment: I just updated it with an XQuery 1.0 example for you too

Comment: Outstanding! That did the trick. Thank you so much for a beautiful solution.